# return function not rendering elements with js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in the given code, the Navbar is being rendered, but the h1 and img is not. On inspecting, they are being rendered but the value inside them is not available. When I tried to debug through console logging, I saw that while inside the useEffect, everything is fine, but after that nothing is being console logged.

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const data_companies = require( "./components/companies.json");
const titleCase = require("./components/titleCase.js");

function CompanyLabel(){
    let data = "";
    let companyName = "";
    let companyLogo = "";

    useEffect(() => {
        data = data_companies;
        console.log("DATA", data);
        
        companyName = window.location.href.split("/company/")[1].replace(/%20/g, " ");
        console.log(companyName);

        data = data[companyName];
        console.log("data of the company", data);

        companyLogo = data.[3].logoLink;
        console.log("logo link of the company", companyLogo);

    }, []);

    companyName = titleCase(companyName);

    return (
        <div className="company-profile">
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <h1>{companyName}</h1>
            <img src={companyLogo} alt={companyName}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompanyLabel;
```

Please help, thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the useEffect hook with an empty array means that it is only going to run that function when the component mounts and when the component unmounts, see:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

So why would you expect the logs to keep on coming?

As for you issue, have you tried setting the variables as state instead?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const data_companies = require( "./components/companies.json");
const titleCase = require("./components/titleCase.js");

function CompanyLabel(){
    const [data, setData] = useState(data_companies); // default value
    const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState("");
    const [companyLogo, setCompanyLogo] = useState("");

useEffect(() => {
        console.log("DATA", data);
        
        setCompanyName(window.location.href.split("/company/")[1].replace(/%20/g, " "));
        console.log(companyName);

        setData(data[companyName]);
        console.log("data of the company", data);

        setCompanyLogo(data[3].logoLink);
        console.log("logo link of the company", companyLogo);

    }, []);
    setCompanyName(titleCase(companyName));
    return (
        <div className="company-profile">
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <h1>{companyName}</h1>
            <img src={companyLogo} alt={companyName}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompanyLabel;
```

This uses the useState hook to define the information as state, providing setters to change that state, allowing the component to re-render when state is changed.

Are you checking your console output errors? The code in your post has a syntax error:

```
companyLogo = data.[3].logoLink;
```

should be

```
companyLogo = data[3].logoLink;
```

Update: In the above, the issue is the final call to setCompanyName, this is called on every render and also triggers a new render. In the above example, either move

```
setCompanyName(titleCase(companyName));
```

into the useEffect callback, or try the below example instead

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";

const data_companies = require( "./components/companies.json");
const titleCase = require("./components/titleCase.js");

function CompanyLabel(){
    const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState(window.location.href.split("/company/")[1].replace(/%20/g, " "));
    const [data, setData] = useState(data_companies[companyName]); // default value
    const [companyLogo, setCompanyLogo] = useState(titleCase(data[3].logoLink));
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("DATA", data);
        console.log(companyName);
        console.log("data of the company", data);
        console.log("logo link of the company", companyLogo);

    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="company-profile">
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <h1>{companyName}</h1>
            <img src={companyLogo} alt={companyName}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CompanyLabel;
```

Comment: Hello, i tried the code that you gave, it's giving the error of ```Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.```

Comment: I added an update. setCompanyName(titleCase(companyName)); is being called outside of useEffect - it's part of the Component function, this means it triggers a render and is also called every render, either move it into the useEffect callback, or use the second solution I provided as an alternative. These are fundamental concepts of the React hook lifecycle, I would recommend you familiarize yourself with how this all works by reading the documentation.

Comment: Your better option would be to move that final setCompanyName call into the callback, or simply remove it and change to: setCompanyLogo(titleCase(data[3].logoLink)); in the previous call